# Network Management Growing messy and ugly need plan

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

Hi i currently have a network management that is really manually and there is no user management at all, i've heard that Microsoft Active Directory allows you to have a better network administration by letting me install and configure equipment remotely by user or groups that would be nice.

Also worried about my Antivirus since its going to expired real soon i don't know if i can get a Low cost alternative to it.

As you can see i am a little bit  overwhelm and i know that the network will eventually grow, so if you please can help me with the following:

How would you approach to this issue?
Is Active Directory a good option? do i have to use Microsoft Server or can i pick an Open source alternative that works as well?
Any comment about the antivirus?

Currently i setup a nice, simple and basic DNS, Proxy, Iptable, DHCP servers...

Thanks

Comment: My advice to you would be to hire a consultant to look at your setup.  I have no idea what your budget is or what your company needs are.

Comment: There are probably some people at careers.stackoverflow.com that can help you out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DHCP and DNS can be handled (and should be, if you're migrating) by AD.

First things first...I think your question is kind of a jumble. You need to sit down, analyze the state of your network, identify what needs to be done, and break the tasks down into manageable chunks. No one here knows your specific needs and configuration, so we can't just design a network for you.

Analyze your situation
identify what needs to be done.
Break the tasks down.
Plan how to fix those issues.
Implement it.

Ask individual questions here for particular situations as they arise.

It also sounds like you may be a bit over your head...don't be afraid to hire consultants to come in and handle some situations as needed, as Holo said. But TAKE TIME TO LEARN WHAT THEY'RE DOING so you don't end up relying on them for everything down the road.